# Prove $\sum_{k=1}^n k \sqrt{k}< 2n^2\sqrt{n} + 3$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I'm trying to prove inequality without using induction. (However, induction here doesn't look pleasantly.)
$$ (\forall n \in \mathbb{Z})(n > 1 \Longrightarrow \sum_{k=1}^n k \sqrt{k}< 2n^2\sqrt{n} + 3)$$

**Edit**: My intention was $ 5 \cdot \sum_{k=1}^n k \sqrt{k}< 2n^2\sqrt{n} + 3$, but I saw my mistake after correct answer appeared, so I decide to leave it as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $k\sqrt{k}<n\sqrt{n}$ for every $k<n$. So $\sum_{k=1}^nk\sqrt{k}<\sum_{k=1}^nn\sqrt{n}=n^2\sqrt{n}<2n^2\sqrt{n}+3$.